# How do you load a helper within a library in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, helper

I created a library for API access, and I created a seperate helper for common functions used by the library. In codeigniter, new libraries can access native classes by creating an instance of themselves using...

$example_instance = & get_instance();

I did this, loaded my helper- but every time the helper function is called i get the "trying to access a non-object" error. What am I doing wrong?

Here's what I have

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

class api_example {
private $api;
public function __construct(){
    $this->api = & get_instance();
    $this->api->load->helper('helper_test');
}   

public function search_recent($param){

    $string = $this->api->helper_test->connect($url); //error!!!

    return $xml;
}


}

/* End of file  */
```

Comment: Just as a precaution.. is the helper file named "helper_test".. punctuation is really what I'm after. It seems like the helper file isn't being loaded.

Comment: Can we take a look at your `helper_test` code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CodeIgniter helpers should be functions, not classes.

Try simply:

```
$string = connect($url);
```

Comment: His class up there is his library. He's trying to load the helper into the library.

Comment: @MattMoore: OK. Doesn't change a thing. I'm glad we're on the same page.

Comment: Wow I completely missed that. A helper is essentially just a function - having a custom class that loads it doesn't change that fact. For some reason my brain just turned off when I created this library ... Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you call a function from a helper.  Helper functions aren't part of the CodeIgniter object.  They're just functions.

```
$string = connect($url);
```